# Error when python check for existing row before add the new row

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote some code for checking the table for existing row and then if the id does not exist, the code inserts new row. Here is the code

```
x.execute("SELECT id FROM headlines WHERE id="+ pid)
numrows = int (x.rowcount)
if numrows<1:
    sql = '''insert into headlinesUS (id,feed_url,item_title,item_date,fetch_date) 
                       values ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s");'''
    x.execute(sql, (pid,url,title,date,fetch))
    connection.commit()
    print("\n- " + title)
```

But when i run it i receive this error:

```
numrows = int (x.rowcount)
                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Check that you don't have any tabs mixed in with your spaces.  If in doubt, delete the whitespace and indent again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check to make sure that your tabs align properly and that you only have spaces or tabs, not both.